# Python Beautiful Soup 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the text inside from the following html structure:

```
<div class="account-places">
    <div>
        <ul class="location-history">
            <li></li>
            <li>Text to extract</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following BeautifulSoup code to do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(html, "lxml")
div = soup.find("div", {"class": "account-places"})
text = div.div.ul.li.next_sibling.get_text()
```

But Beautiful Soup is throwing the error: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you need `find_next_sibling("li")`.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(html, "lxml")
div = soup.find("div", {"class": "account-places"})
text = div.div.ul.li.find_next_sibling("li").get_text()
print(text)
```

**Output:**

```
Text to extract
```

Comment: what do you do to grab text that's outside the string?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `next_sibling`call returns a NavigableString, you have to follow that syntax:

```
text = unicode(div.div.ul.li.next_sibling)
```

To quote [the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring):

> A NavigableString is just like a Python Unicode string, except that it
>   also supports some of the features described in Navigating the tree
>   and Searching the tree. You can convert a NavigableString to a Unicode
>   string with unicode()